# Facebook iOS app Newsfeed UITableViewCell, how did they implemented it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, feed

I need to implement newsfeed `UITableView` list (like in facebook app), and I wonder which `UIKit` components I should use.
Do you know how (short overview) **facebook iOS app** implemented it?
Should I use `UIWebView`? or
 
Should I use **third party** `UILabel` library that supports HTML tags?
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This article written by the person responsible for Facebook iOS app says they use the CoreText framework to style the text.

http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-rebuilding-facebook-for-ios/10151036091753920

They stopped using HTML5 for the native iOS app last August, so I doubt that the UITableViewCells are using UIWebViews which is quite slow.